# Решённый-перерешённый, заложенный-перезаложенный - единственное отступление от правила?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Вопрос о правильном написании усилительных сочетаний-повторов. Н и НН в формах страдательных причастий и соотносительных с ними прилагательных.

Comment: Вы бы хоть правило сформулировали, на которое ссылаетесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галина, это как раз не исключение из правила, а полное ему соответствие. Вот правило у Лопатина:

В словах с приставкой не-, в сложных словах и в некоторых сочетаниях-повторах формы причастий и прилагательных пишутся так же, как в отдельном (без приставки и не в составе сложного слова или сочетания-повтора) употреблении, т. е. по правилам § 98. Примеры:

1. Слова с приставкой не-:

пишутся с нн: необразованный, нелинованный, непроверенный, незаконченный, некупленный, непрощённый',
пишутся с н: небелёный, неглаженый, незваный, некованый, некормленый, некрашеный, немереный, немощёный, непаханый, непрошеный, несчитаный.

2. Сложные слова:

пишутся с нн: высококвалифицированный, цельноштампован-ный, благоприобретённый, свежеокрашенный, целенаправленный, слепорождённый, умалишённый',

пишутся с н: гладкокрашеный, домотканый, мелкодроблёный, самозваный, тяжелораненый, цельнокроеный.

3. Сочетания-повторы с приставкой пере- во второй части, имеющие усилительное значение. В них **вторая часть пишется так же, как первая** (с нн или
   н), напр.:

**пишутся с нн:
 заложенный-перезаложенный, решённый-перерешённый;**

**пишутся с н:**

*латаный-перелатаный, стираный-перестираный, чиненый-перечиненый, читаный-перечитаный, штопаный-перештопаный.*

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2132

Comment: Люсенька, вот я и спрашиваю: единственно вынесенные в шапку вопроса два слова с двумя нн? Проблема в том, что я вчера поправила человека - с двух н на одно - во фразе "...многажды жеваННые-пережёваННые". А человек вполне грамотный. А я с этим правилом. И когда поезд ушёл бесповоротно, обнаружила (знаки кончаются, перенесу фрагмент правила и ссылку в следующий коммент) эту заложенность с решённостью... Чем жёванность хуже решённости?

Comment: *Особый интерес представляет написание (в современной практике письма весьма неустойчивое) усилительных сочетаний-повторов типа стираный-перестираный, штопаный-перештопаный. Сохранять ли во второй части таких сочетаний одно н, как в первой части, или все же писать два н? Предлагается писать во второй части столько же н, сколько в первой: глаженый-переглаженый, жёваный-пережёваный, читаный-перечитаный, но: решённый-перерешённый, заложенный-перезаложенный.* http://fanread.net/book/10766985/?page=9 Вот это "но" очень трогательное. Как бы и всё на этом?

Comment: Галина, вот правило. Пишутся также с нн причастия не на -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов совершенного вида и соотносительные с ними прилагательные; подавляющее большинство таких глаголов содержит приставку.

Comment: Сюда относятся: перечень форм исконно бесприставочных глаголов, а также некоторых глаголов, приставка в которых может быть выделена только этимологически:решённый(бесприставочный глагол) и заложенный ( приставочный).

Comment: жёваный -от глагола несов вида, поэтому одно Н, жёваный - пережёваный - одно Н, а решённый (что сделать) - сов. вид, правда, без приставки, поэтому две -НН-.Но в той фразе ещё и странное " многажды", а это зависимое слово, разве оно не превращает слово в причастие? Всё выражение просторечное, трудно говорить о норме, но зависимое слово предполагает НН.

Comment: Так что ,видимо, зря исправили, "...многажды жеваННые-пережёваННые". верно, -НН-

Comment: Мне не приходят извещения о комментариях; Люсенька и Сержик - спасибо! Почему два слова с повтором (из шапки) безоговорочно причастия, а *жёваный-пережёваный* аж в два словаря попал(о) - полное молчание о зависимых словах. И тогда *многажды читаННый-перечитаННый*? Зачем их тогда списком для запоминания дают, эти причастия с одним н?!

Comment: Людмила,мне кажется, что здесь зависимое слово "многажды" стоит не при причастии, а при прилагательном.

Comment: Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда зависимое слово не является признаком причастия. Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Comment: Серж, смотря какие зависимые слова,"явно","раньше/позже/теперь" могут относиться и к прилагательным, но "многажды"= много раз, а "много  раз сделанное" - это уже причастие. Крашеный пол - прилагательное, а много раз крашенный пол - причастие.Белёные стены-прилагательное, а много раз беленные стены - причастие.

Comment: Galina, два слова с повтором (из шапки) не безоговорочно   причастия, это могут быть отглагольные прилагательные(решённый вопрос=ясный, заложенный нос=болезненно полный), но пишутся с 2 "Н", потому что образованы  от глаголов сов вида. А список для запоминания как раз даётся отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от глаголов несовершенного вида в значении совершенного: желанный, священный,нечаянный, негаданный, невиданный, неслыханный,нежданный,медленный, венчанный, недрема′нное око, пивоваренный, доморощенный,штукатуренный,считанные минуты, деланный смех.

Comment: И некоторые из них могут употребляться и в усилительных повторах: виданный-перевиданный, слыханный-переслыханный,штукатуренный-перештукатуренный.